# ObjectiveC UIImage update view blocking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I have the weirdest of bugs. I have two UIImageView in the storyboard, a big one, lets call it A, and a small one, B. I animate the position of the small one in the view controller, and that works fine.

However: when I try to replace the background image of A, suddenly, B snaps to its original position in the storyboard and it won't budge. Here's the thing: I've conducted tests, and I noticed that if A does not exceed a certain width, B can be moved, and it does not snap back. I have tried changing the image of A after a delay, using [self performSelector:] with a timeout in the view controller, but just when I change the image, B snaps back to its position in the storyboard. I have no idea how this is even possible, although it does look like a memory issue to me.

Here's my animation code:

```
CGRect newFrame = self.B.frame;
newFrame.origin.x = newX; // defined earlier

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.1];

[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Moving" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Moving from %g to %d!", self.B.frame.origin.x, newX] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

self.B.frame = newFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: post your animation code

Comment: I did, please look at the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an inadvertent constraint between the two image views that is getting applied when A is bigger.

Comment: What is a constraint between two image views? And how do I get rid of it?

Comment: @arik-so are you using autolayout?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: When you create storyboards by dragging stuff onto controller views, you can get constraints created.  Check the objects in the 'Document Outline', looking for 'Constraints' Delete the ones that exist between your imageView A and B.

Comment: I don't have any constraints between these to objects, although both are aligned centrally. Also, I cannot delete any of those constraints, because promoting them to user constraints and deleting them makes them reappear. And lastly, why would changing the image of one UIImagevView reposition the other?

Comment: I have just noticed that AutoLayout had been checked. That sneaky thing.